# How to disable popover animation in v-calendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vcalendar

The problem related to this package

https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar

Problem: I try to figure out, how to disable popover animation fade-in and fade-out in the DatePicker component.

Additional info:
I guess source code related to my problem stores here
https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/blob/2b6bdc6cfe7d2317eef075b60be177b615ee56de/src/components/Popover.vue

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0aLvw6gb/)

1. I recommend to add `:transition="'none'"` for `<v-date-picker/>` element to disable transitions in calendar.
2. If you are using `input slot` to show popover, you can specify popover options in `onclick` function.

```
 <v-date-picker :transition="'none'">
    <template v-slot="{ inputValue, togglePopover }">
      <input :value="inputValue"
             @click="togglePopover({ placement: 'bottom', transition: 'none', showDelay: 0, hideDelay: 0 })"
             />
    </template>
  </v-date-picker>
```

*[List of all popover options](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/blob/master/src/components/Popover.vue#L71-L85)*

Answer (score 0):

in case someone needs I found this way to change popover visibility of v-date-picker component

```
v-date-picker :popover="{ visibility: 'click' }"
```